# Sql select by multiple values from select with many joins

Tags: sql, performance, join, where-clause

I have following sql query and i would like to optimize it to work faster.

```
select dv.Id, dv.Version, cvco.Time
from DVPST dvps  -- cca. 10 000 entries
  inner join DVPCT dvpc ON dvps.Value = dvpc.Value 
  inner join DVPT dvp on dvpc.Id = dvp.Id
  inner join DVT dv on dvp.Id = dv.Id 
  inner join CVCOT cvco ON dv.Id = cvco.Id 
  inner join DT doc on doc.Id = dv.Id
where dvps.ValueStr in ("value1", "value2", ..., "value1000")
```

Execution plan evalutes all using correct indexes but it still takes so long. The where condition should filter all entries from DVPCT table so only this is evaluated in most cases:

```
select dv.Id, dv.Version, cvco.Time
from DVPST dvps
where dvps.ValueStr in ("value1", "value2", ..., "value10000")
```

Why does the query still executes the joins when it have nothing to join there.

Many thanks for any ideas, 
Marek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to execute the main query in a WITH [...] AS and then the join. Maybe it's faster:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT Value
        FROM DVPST
        WHERE ValueStr IN ("value1", "value2", ..., "value1000")
)

SELECT dv.Id, dv.Version, cvco.Time
    FROM t
    INNER JOIN DVPCT dvpc ON t.Value = dvpc.Value 
    INNER JOIN DVPT dvp ON dvpc.Id = dvp.Id
    INNER JOIN DVT dv ON dvp.Id = dv.Id 
    INNER JOIN CVCOT cvco ON dv.Id = cvco.Id 
    INNER JOIN DT doc ON doc.Id = dv.Id
```

Or try with #tempTable (it can be faster in certain cases):

```
SELECT Value
    INTO #table
    FROM DVPST
WHERE ValueStr IN ("value1", "value2", ..., "value1000")

SELECT dv.Id, dv.Version, cvco.Time
    FROM #table t
    INNER JOIN DVPCT dvpc ON t.Value = dvpc.Value 
    INNER JOIN DVPT dvp ON dvpc.Id = dvp.Id
    INNER JOIN DVT dv ON dvp.Id = dv.Id 
    INNER JOIN CVCOT cvco ON dv.Id = cvco.Id 
    INNER JOIN DT doc ON doc.Id = dv.Id
```

Let me know if it helped.

*Note: are you sure this INNER JOIN is really needed?*

```
inner join DT doc on doc.Id = dv.Id
```

Comment: Thank you! the second query is really faster and works on mysql too. The join is needed, I've reduced the query to make it more readable.